# Overlapping with Fusion Chart

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fusioncharts

While I drag an element (DIV or SPAN or any ), over the FusionChart control, the draggable element disappears. Sometimes the elements comes under the FusionChart. I need  to drag the element over the Fusion Chart control. Here I am using Drag and Drop using jQuery. And i am dragging a text. What is the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the SWF's wmode parameter to "transparent".

```
var Chart1 = new FusionCharts(this.chart, "ChartId1", this.width, this.height);
Chart1.addParam("WMode", "Transparent"); // this line is the one you're looking for
Chart1.setDataXML(this.dataxml);
Chart1.render(this.chart1div);
```

Example code [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic3891-35-1.aspx).

Comment: I didnt understand. How to change ? and where ?

Comment: I got the solution as by placing this line 
where should I place the tag “<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>”.
Where should I place this ?

Comment: You usually set that in the <object> tag, but I believe FusionCharts generates it's own HTML. If you are calling FusionChars with JavaScript try the example I just added to my answer above.